# Azure DocumentDB and Azure Blob Storage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage

I'm using azure document db in my ASP.net MVC application.And currently I'm having 2 collections in it which are Employees and Tasks. Currently everything is working fine with document db operations.

But I couldn't find a way to upload multiple images(not multiple images at once )
against a document. *eg: assume I need to store 2 employee pictures against a single employee document.*

I've read about the azure blob storage and think I can use it for the file uploads.But the thing that I can unable to clarify is how to **keep the references of the uploaded files in each employee documents**.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 5):

> I've read about the azure blob storage and think I can use it for the
>   file uploads.But the thing that I can unable to clarify is how to keep
>   the references of the uploaded files in each employee documents.

Each blob in blob storage is accessible via a URL. What you could do is save these URLs along with the document. For example, your Employee JSON could look like:

```
Employee = {
  'Id': '0001',
  'Name': 'Some Name',
  'Pictures': [
    'https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/image1.png',
    'https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/image2.png'
  ]
}
```

Other thing you could do is look at [`Attachments`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/documentdb-resources/#attachments-and-media) in DocumentDB.

Comment: So can I get this URL when I upload a file?

Comment: Yes. Please see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961933/how-to-get-blob-url-after-file-upload-in-azure/16962331#16962331.