# Get URI of uploaded blob?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

Consider the following code:

```
// _blobContainerClient is an instance of BlobContainerClient
await _blobContainerClient.UploadBlobAsync(uniqueName, stream);

string uri = < how to get the URI? >
```

How do I get the URI of the uploaded blob?

I am using `Azure.Storage.Blobs` 12.8.0.

Comment: Is this helpful - [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961933/how-to-get-blob-url-after-file-upload-in-azure/16962331])?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to create a client and return the Uri this,

```
var blob = new BlobClient(connectionString, containerName, fileName);
await blob.UploadAsync(fileStream, o);
return ReturnUri(blob.Uri);
```

Comment: Thanks! Hint: It's also possible to just do `_blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(uniqueName)` to get a `BlobClient`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do more things with the blob object, I would recommend creating a new [BlobClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient?view=azure-dotnet). If you just need the URI this should work as well:

`var blobUri = $"{_blobContainerClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri}/{uniqueName}"`;

Comment: thanks! wasn't aware of this URI pattern. for other readers, I found this later: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#resource-uri-syntax